# Почему выскакивает events.js:183 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event?

Tags: gulp

Ошибка появляется при попытке запустить gulp imageMin, не понимаю в чем ошибка.

```
    npm -v
    5.4.2
    node -v
    v8.9.3
    gulp -v
[23:48:32] CLI version 3.9.1
[23:48:32] Local version 3.9.1
```

Вот код ошибки:

```
 $ gulp imageMin
[23:44:24] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\Projects\robot\gulpfile.js
[23:44:24] Starting 'imageMin'...

events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: ���⥬� �� 㤠���� ���� 㪠����� ����.

    at notFoundError (C:\Users\Администратор\Desktop\Projects\robot\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:11:11)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\Администратор\Desktop\Projects\robot\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:46:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\Администратор\Desktop\Projects\robot\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:33:19)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
```

Comment: уточните есть ли кириллические символы в пути к файлу

Comment: Столкнулся с аналогичной ошибкой. Если вы решили отпишитесь пожалуйста